# Running Spatialite on iOS in Java Giving Error Although I Have Packages Installed

Tags: java, sqlite, integration-testing, dependency-management, spatialite

I use iOS Catalina and I need to run some tests in Java for loading data to Spatialite. I am encountering with this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'sqlite3_enable_load_extension, symbol not found
```

I have already installed and updated sqlite3 and spatialite with homebrew.

I added sqlite to my path in my bash_profile:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/sqlite/bin:$PATH"
```

My collegues using Ubuntu have these packages installed but I couldn't equivalent ones:

```
sqlite3, spatialite-bin, libsqlite3-mod-spatialite
```

What else do I need to do to run Spatialite on iOS?